# Angular 2 TypeScript JSON Show in view

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I have problem with this Angular 2 TS JSONs. I was programing AngularJS in the past but now i am trying Angular 2 and TS . I can't understend how the Json response working here when i am trying to show them on view. I know that this type of show one value in selector opiton is wrong dont worry about it.

```
<tr *ngFor="let task of tasks;let myIndex = index">
        <th> {{myIndex+1}}</th>
        <td>{{task.title}}</td>
        <td>{{task.CreateDate}}</td>
        <td>{{task.CurentMoney}}</td>
        <td>
            <select class="form-control"  id="sel1">
                <option>{{ task.History.month}}</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
```

Somthing like Task maping class .

```
export class Task{
_id:string;
title: string;
CreateDate: string;
CurentMoney: number;
isDone: boolean;
History: { month: string, monthMoney:number}[];}
```

Controler:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {TaskService} from '../../services/task.service';
import {Task} from '../../../Task';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'tasks',
  templateUrl: 'tasks.component.html'
})

export class TasksComponent {
    bankName: string;
    tasks: Task[];
    title: string;
    CreateDate: string;
    CurentMoney: number;


    constructor(private taskService:TaskService){
        this.taskService.getTasks()
            .subscribe(tasks => {
                this.tasks = tasks;
            });
    } 
testObj(){

    console.log(this.tasks);
}...}
```

Servivce:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Task} from "../../Task";

@Injectable()
export class TaskService{
    constructor(private http:Http){
        console.log('Task Service Initialized...');
    }

    getTasks(){
        return this.http.get('/api/tasks')
            .map(res => <Task[]>res.json());
    }
```

When I call testobj() i have right console output json, but on the view i can't do task.History.month for example.

Comment: your json sample?

Comment: {
    "_id" : ObjectId("58efb109420c1f2340bbb31a"),
    "title" : "bank",
    "CreateDate" : "2017-04-13",
    "CurentMoney" : "123",
    "isDone" : false,
    "History" : [ 
        {
            "month" : "December",
            "monthMoney" : "200000"
        }, 
        {
            "month" : "jaunary",
            "monthMoney" : "300000"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using custom defined types as

```
export interface Task{
    _id:string;
    title: string;
    createDate: string;
    curentMoney: number;
    isDone: boolean;
    history: Array<History>;
}
export interface History 
{ 
    month: string, 
    monthMoney:number

}
```

Update :
 As you are nesting an array inside, you need to use another ngFor to loop into it as below

```
<div *ngFor="let task of tasks"> 
        <p *ngFor="let item of task.History">Test: {{item.month}}</p> 
</div>
```

Comment: When i am try this i have :
HTML TEST:
    <div *ngFor="let task of tasks">
            <p>Test: {{task.History | json}}</p>
        </div>
View: Test: [ { "month": "jau", "monthMoney": "200000" }, { "month": "December", "monthMoney": "300000" } ]
and i got :
When i am change it for 
 <div *ngFor="let task of tasks">
            <p>Test: {{task.History.month}}</p>
        </div>
core.umd.js:3427 EXCEPTION: Error in http://localhost:3000/app/components/tasks/tasks.component.html:17:15 caused by: Cannot read property 'month' of undefined

Comment: are you getting the data from the service?

Comment: Cannot read property 'month' of undefined i cant go into array everything is showing good only things in array are like not "included".

Comment: Yes , u got it in the post.

Comment: did you check if you have made any typo?

Comment: How to check it? the main question for me is why i got a good output console.log and i cant work with this json at the view.

Comment: Ah well, it's work perfect now ... bad structure of date(Task) and loop.
Thank u very much.  i was trying to make i like <div *ngFor="let task of tasks.History"> and that was not working ..